# How to display function passed parameters as iframe src

Tags: html, iframe

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
<title>Info</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function fn(name){
    document.getElementById("link").src = name;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contain">
        <div id="head">
            <h1 align="center">Represent</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="list">
            <a href="NewFile1.html" onclick='fn("NewFile1.html")'>file1</a><br>
            <a href="NewFile2.html" onclick='fn("NewFile2.html")'>file2</a><br>
            <a href="">nasdd</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fr">
        <iframe id="link" align="left" src="about:blank" style="width: 78%;>
        </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link say 'file1', the correct html is displayed but not in the iframe and is displayed as a new page. How to display the html only in the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working!!
I just did :

```
<a href="NewFile1.html" onclick='return fn("NewFile1.html")'>file1</a><br>
<a href="NewFile2.html" onclick='return fn("NewFile2.html")'>file2</a><br>

function fn(name){
    document.getElementById("link").src = name;
    return false;
}
```